# Structs, pointers, and trees in C

Tags: c, filesystems, tree

For our final semester project, everyone in my Operating Systems class has been tasked with implementing a pseudo "linux filesystem". The idea is to simulate handling files, folders, changing directories, and so forth.

I dislike having to work with Strings and pointers when I program in C, and unfortunately for my peace-of-mind, this project looks to involve both. Because I am relatively uncomfortable with pointers, I was hoping I could get a sanity check that my backend implementation of the underlying tree structure is sound.

```
typedef struct floorNode
{
    char floorName[30]; //the name of the tree node
    struct floorNode *parentPointer; //this is a pointer to the parent node. Null for the root node.
    struct floorNode *childPointers[10]; //this is an array holding pointers to up to 10 child nodes. 
    char fileArray[10][30]; //this is an array of 10 'files', each of up to length 30.
                            //for this assignment, strings are the only type of "file"

} floorNode;
```

Is this the proper way to implement a tree in C?

Comment: You're not going to be able to much of anything in C if you don't like working with pointers. BTW, most languages have pointers, they just try to hide it by calling them references but most of the same issues apply.

Comment: @mu is too short - I like references much better, though that might just be my greater volume of experience with them talking.

Comment: It's fine that all you wanted is a filesystem with a limitation that there must be less than 10 files and subdirectories in one directory. And I think it makes no sense to store the absolute name of the node. I hope you can figure out why

Comment: @J.S. Taylor it royally screws up results from a 'ls' command for one thing. Yup. I came to that conclusion as well.

Comment: @Raven: But references only solve the NULL pointer problem and usually help you with the memory management problem. One of the trickiest parts of pointers is having to deal with multiple pointers pointing at the same thing and references don't help you there. And this probably isn't the best site to be saying that you [don't like pointers](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html) on :)

Comment: @mu is too short - Ouch. I guess at least I like recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is more or less the proper data type.

I'm concerned about `fileArray[][]`.  I don't think it is needed, unless I'm misunderstanding its purpose.  To get `floorName` of the children, instead traverse `childPointers[]` to obtain the name in the children.

Something to consider if the nodes have 30 character strings is to make the storage for all of them a little bigger, 31 in this case, so that a trailing NUL is always present and no special yucky handling is needed to distinguish between a 30-character string without a NUL and all the shorter strings which have one.

Comment: file array is for children that aren't themselves floorNodes. (In my case, they're just simple strings instead). Now then, with my luck, I'm betting Stack Overflow will soon have another question on me complaining about my trees not working :P

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a linked list of children. You definitely don't want arrays of pointers for this. You should also think about how to know if a file is actually a directory.

Comment: you're suggesting that each node have a linked list of children?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer - Yes. I'd also consider that directories and regular files are both files and should be in the tree as the same kind of node.